# I dont know why it wont run (js)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The problem is the script won't find the selected cell. I have tried chatgpt and no work at all.

```
 javascript
```

```
function moveImportedData() {
  // Open the source and target spreadsheets by their IDs and get the specific sheets.
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hoyVaEtnff-XqkVzSahi0l_sFhxO0TAnwOGhDg9mg1c').getSheetByName('Pew');
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1iIQf6VYTlG9ANKBkYnXsP_e1dupS9vgZcUye5DQzki0').getSheetByName('October')

  // Get the current date.
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // Get the script properties, which are used to store data between script runs.
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  // Get the initial offset from script properties, default to 42 if not set.
  var initialOffset = scriptProperties.getProperty('offset');
  if (!initialOffset) {
    initialOffset = 3;
  }

  // Calculate the day number based on the difference between the current date and January 1, 2023, in milliseconds.
  var dayNumber = Math.floor((currentDate - new Date("2023-01-01")) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + initialOffset;

  // Construct the cell reference in the source sheet based on the calculated day number.
  var sourceCellReference = 'D' + dayNumber;

  // Get the data from the source cell in the source sheet.
  var cellValue = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceCellReference).getValue();

  // Check if the cell contains a value.
  if (cellValue !== "") {
    // Check the data type of the cell value (string or number).
    if (typeof cellValue === 'string' || typeof cellValue === 'number') {
      // Set the imported data into a specific cell in the target sheet.
      targetSheet.getRange('C4').setValue(cellValue);

      // Increment the offset for the next script run.
      scriptProperties.setProperty('offset', parseInt(initialOffset) + 1);
    } else {
      // Log a message if the cell value is not a string or number.
      Logger.log("Source cell contains unsupported data type. No data imported.");
    }
  } else {
    // Log a message if the source cell is empty.
    Logger.log("Source cell is empty. No data imported.");
  }
}
```

I have put two spreadsheet A and B. I wanted the the data taken from a cell at spreadsheet A to be automatically to be selected one cell down, every day or specific time. Here is my GitHub.

Everything needed is here
https://github.com/Hayami0/JavaScript-for-Sheets.git

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please do not just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77393001/edit) and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function moveImportedData() {
  var ssh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hoyVaEtnff-XqkVzSahi0l_sFhxO0TAnwOGhDg9mg1c').getSheetByName('Pew');
  var tsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1iIQf6VYTlG9ANKBkYnXsP_e1dupS9vgZcUye5DQzki0').getSheetByName('October')
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var initoff = parseInt(sp.getProperty('offset'));
  if (!initoff) {
    initoff = 3;
    sp.setProperty("offset", 3);
  }
  var dayNumber = DiffInDays(new Date(),new Date(2023,0,1)) + initoff;
  var cellValue = ssh.getRange(dayNumber, 4).getValue();
  if (cellValue !== "") {
    if (typeof cellValue === 'string' || typeof cellValue === 'number') {
      tsh.getRange(4, 3).setValue(cellValue);
      sp.setProperty('offset', parseInt(initoff) + 1);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Source cell contains unsupported data type. No data imported.");
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log("Source cell is empty. No data imported.");
  }
}

function DiffInDays(Day1, Day2) {
  if (Day1 && Day2 && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day1) === '[object Date]') && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day2) === '[object Date]')) {
    var day = 86400000;
    var t1 = new Date(Day1).valueOf();
    var t2 = new Date(Day2).valueOf();
    var d = Math.abs(t2 - t1);
    var days = Math.floor(d / day);
    //Logger.log(days);
    return days;
  } else {
    throw 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

- [Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

"

- 1 Check execution log for errors.
- 2 Use a try catch(e) with a console log or logger log in the catch statement.

Comment: One of the problems in your code was the attempt to subtract two dates without using methods that return the date in numerical format like valueOf() or getTime()